# How to save items loaded in a repeater?

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I am loading a set of records that load in a `Repeater` control.  I have a `CheckBox` control for each record that determines whether the item is Active/Inactive.  How do I loop through all the records in the `Repeater` on a button click event and save the state of the `CheckBox`?  I will need to get the ID of the record and the Checked state of the control.

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's a few ways to approach it. If you are not re-binding the data on PostBack (e.g. you are relying on the already-populated repeater), you need to write the record ID to some field that will be persisted in ViewState. In this example I've used a [HiddenField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hiddenfield.aspx):

```
void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(RepeaterItem item in myRepeater.Items)
    {
        CheckBox cbxIsActive = item.FindControl("cbxID") as CheckBox;
        HiddenField hdfID = item.FindControl("recordID") as HiddenField;
        if(cbxIsActive != null && hdfID != null)
        {
            string recordID = hdfID.Value;
            bool isActive = cbxIsActive.Checked;
            UpdateRecord(recordID, isActive);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice. I didn't realize it would be so easy.  Thanks!!